# Adjectif possessif ou article défini ?

Tags: articles, possessif

Quand on utilise un verbe réfléchi qui prend une partie du corps comme l'objet direct, on ne peut pas utiliser un adjectif possessif avec l'objet direct.

> Je me suis lavé **les** mains (pas: **mes** mains)

Si on utilise un verbe normal, la situation reste-t-elle la même, ou change-t-elle ?

> J'ai levé **la** main.
>
> J'ai levé **ma** main.
>
> Ils ont levé **les** mains.
>
> Ils ont levé **leurs** mains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's another case where you should use the definite article for body parts: verbs denoting *movement*. For example:

> J'ai levé **la** main. (Et pas "ma main")
>
> Il lève **la** tête. (Et pas "sa tête")
>
> Pourquoi tournes-tu **la** tête ? (Et pas "ta tête")
>
> J'ai mis les pieds sous la table.

The usage with verbs of movement and the definite article describes when the limb or body part is making an "autonomous" movement. It would be understandable to use a possessive article instead, but that would mean something a bit different where the limb or body part is a passive object being moved. For example:

> J'ai levé ma paupière avec les doigts pour récupérer la lentille qui s'était coincée dessous. (It's not the eyelid that lifted itself.)
>
> J'ai posé mes fesses sur le canapé. (The butt was passive.)
>
> En tirant dessus, j'ai soulevé ma jambe droite, qui était paralysée.

Aside from that, I would say you need to use the possessive:

> Je regarde **ma** main. (Et pas "la main". Mais "je me regarde la main" est correct.)
>
> Il lave **sa** figure. (Et pas "la figure". Mais "il se lave la figure" est correct et plus naturel.)
>
> Je soigne **mon** nez. (Et pas "le nez". Mais "je me soigne le nez" est aussi correct.)

Now, on a bit of a tangent, I think there's a regional usage which I've heard in Southern France and extends the use of the definite article to clothes and accessories in addition to body parts:

> Il fait froid, je vais mettre **le** manteau. (Plus standard : "mon manteau" ou "un manteau".)
>
> Il a enlevé **la** chemise. (Plus standard : "sa chemise".)

Comment: "Il se lave la figure" is IMHO more common. "Je soigne mon nez" could maybe have another connotation, like "I really pay attention to that nose (and do something special about it)". "Il fait froid, je vais mettre le manteau", to me, sounds rural more than southern. Same for "la chemise". My wife is from the north east countryside, and they could say that in her family.

Comment: Thanks. Clarified that "il se lave la figure" is more natural-sounding, though the point was to say that with non-reflexive verbs and aside from those of movement you would need "ma" rather than "la". Also clarified that I've heard the regional use I'm talking about in the South, but without ruling out that it exists elsewhere.

Comment: It's hard for me (I'm French) to explain the differences - we just assimilate these things as kids, without thinking very hard about it. I was surprised to hear about "movement verbs" - or I forgot that it was taught that way in school. I cannot really explain either why "se laver la figure" is "natural", but "enlever la chemise" can sound "rural". Maybe that one depends also on context and tone.

Answer (score 2):

Effectivement, utiliser "mon/ma/mes" avec un verbe non réfléchi semble plus acceptable.

> J'ai levé ma main.
>
> Ils ont levé leurs mains.

Ces deux phrases ne semblent pas très naturelles (et du coup, on s'attend a ce que ce "mes" ou ce "leurs" soient là exprès, que l'auteur va parler de cette main en particulier (?)), mais je dirais que c'est acceptable.

> J'ai levé la main.
> Ils ont levé la main.

semble meilleur, peut-être parce que "lever la main" est devenu une expression toute faite.

Comment: Et si on utilise une expression qui n'est pas toute faite ? Par exemple "J'ai levé mon bras", "J'ai levé mon pied" ou "J'ai levé ma jambe". Devrait-on utiliser "mon/ma" ou "le/la" ici ?

Comment: Les deux sont corrects. Ca dépend du contexte, je suppose. Mais "j'ai levé la jambe" est peut-être un peu plus courant.

Comment: @user11550 Je pense qu'utiliser le possessif insiste beaucoup sur la possession. Quand on dit "j'ai levé la main", l'important est l'action de lever, alors que dans "j'ai levé ma main", l'important est que ce soit ma main qui se soit levé, et pas la main du voisin... de même pour toutes les autres parties du corps...